# Pandas - Extracting value from a key

Tags: pandas

I am trying to extract some data from Salesforce and come across the below value. I am trying to extract the value of a column of type "object.

```
{'attributes': {'type': 'Case', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Case/3456423456543'}, 'Ticket': '25432'}
```

Trying to pull value corresponding to 'Ticket'. Expected Output : 25432

Comment: di['Ticket'] should give you the ticket and di['attributes']['type'] should give you the type within the attributes.

Comment: @Jorge thanks for that